# What locator should I use to get a list of elements that switch the page in Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am making a project and for it I need to get several clickable elements in a list from [a search result](https://www.allmovie.com/search/all/matrix). The code I tried to use is as follows

```
           By resultsLocator = By.className("title");
           List<WebElement>  results = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(resultsLocator));
```

The problem here is that clicking on elements in this list doesn't change the page to a movie page. I think the problem here is the locator, but I don't know how to generalize it to get what I need. What locator should I use to make this work? Alternative solution are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to open the movie pages you can see the following XPath locator:

```
//li[@class='movie']//div[@class='title']//a[@href]
```

These are exactly the links contained below the title per each search result.